# How can I get the EmbeddedId from my Entity

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have a question to my tables / entities.

My SQL-Table is like the following:

Table 1:

IdTable1 (pk) 
Properties...

---

Table 2:

IdTable2 (pk) 
Properties...

---

Table 3:

IdTable1 (pk) 
IdTable2 (pk) 
Date

---

Ok.. Now I have in Java JPA the following Eintities:

Table1

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Table1 {

private Long table1Id

protected Table1() {
    super();
}

protected Table1(Long table1Id) {
    super();
    this.table1Id = table1Id;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Table1) {
        Table1 fach = (Table1) obj;
        return this.getTable1Id().equals(fach.getTable1Id());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Id
@Column(name = "IDTABLE1")
public Long getTable1Id() {
    return table1Id;
}

public void setTable1Id(Long table1Id) {
    this.table1Id = table1Id;
}
}
```

Table2

```
@Entity
public class Table2 {

private Long table2Id

protected Table2() {
    super();
}

protected Table2(Long table2Id) {
    super();
    this.table2Id = table2Id;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Table2) {
        Table2 fach = (Table2) obj;
        return this.getTable2Id().equals(fach.getTable2Id());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Id
@Column(name = "IDTABLE2")
public Long getTable2Id() {
    return table12d;
}

public void setTable2Id(Long table2Id) {
    this.table2Id = table2Id;
}
}
```

Table3

```
@Entity
public class Table3 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Table3Id table3Id;
private Date date;

public Table3() {
    super();
}

public Table3(Date date, Table1 table1, Table2 table2) {
    super();
    this.date = date;
    this.table3Id = new Table3Id(table1, table2);
}

@EmbeddedId
public Table3Id getTable3Id() {
    return table3Id;
}

public void setTable3Id(Table3Id table3Id) {
    this.table3Id = table3Id;
}

@Column(name = "date", nullable = true)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Table3Id

```
@Embeddable
public class Table3Id implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Table1 table1;
private Table2 table2;

public Table3Id() {
}

public Table3Id(Table1 table1, Table2 table2) {
    this.table1 = table1;
    this.table2 = table2;
}

public Table1 getTable1() {
    return table1;
}

public void setTable1(Table1 table1) {
    this.table1 = table1;
}

public Table2 getTable2() {
    return table2;
}

public void setTable2(Table2 table2) {
    this.table2 = table2;
}
}
```

Ok... How can I now get the Table3 Properties from my Dao-Object with: ?

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select t from Table3 as t")
```

---

**EDIT**

Its like [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Embedded_Primary_Key_), but I have Entities (f.e. Table1 table1; Table2 table2) in my EntitiyId and not "long table1id; long table2id".

---

**EDIT**

I think @Niemand 's query is the right but I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Table1, at table: Table3, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(table1)]
```

Comment: It is not clear what the exact relationship is between these entities? If T2 extends T1 with a Joined strategy they would typically share a primary key. Does either T1 or T2 have a one-to-many with T3?

Comment: Table 3 has a Composite  Primary Key (table1id + table2id) and has a foreign Key contraint to table1id and table2id

Comment: I mean a foreign Key contraint to IdTable1 and IdTable2

Comment: @AlanHay please look my edits

Answer (score 0):

`Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select t.table3Id.table1, t.table3Id.table2 from Table3 as t")`

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Table1, at table: Table3, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(table1)]